# Using Context to pass a variable to a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Having issues getting a variable to pass to the template, example below:

```
def confirm(request, reference):

    c = {'return_reference': reference}

    msg_plain = render_to_string('mail.txt', c)
    msg_html = render_to_string('mail.html')
    send_mail(
        'Return - Ready for Collection',
        msg_plain,
        'some@sender.com',
        ['some@receiver.com'],
        html_message=msg_html,
        )
```

And my HTML template:

`<p>Return reference <strong>{{ return_reference }}</strong>....`

Anyway, the result of this is always a blank / null in the return reference... Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: you are sending the context to your .txt file, but you have used that variable in your html file. Is that a typo? try passing the context to the html as well

Comment: Yes, a typo :( that's embarrassing, I spent way too long debugging this!!!

Answer (score 0):

You've forgot to pass the context to your `msg_html` `render_to_string`

I will suggest you to generate the html message and from there the plain one using html2text, something as follows:

```py
from html2text import html2text  # import html2text module

def confirm(request, reference):

    c = {'return_reference': reference}

    msg_html = render_to_string('mail.html', c)  # render html message
    msg_plain = html2text(msg_html)  # create plain message variant
    send_mail(
        'Return - Ready for Collection',
        msg_plain,
        'some@sender.com',
        ['some@receiver.com'],
        html_message=msg_html,
        )
```